# How do I determine which test is hanging?

Tags: java, maven, testing, intellij-idea, testng

I have a test that's hanging... when I attempt to run the tests from Maven, it always ends with ManagedLedgerTest, like this:

```
[INFO] Running org.apache.bookkeeper.client.PulsarMockReadHandle
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.028 s - in org.apache.bookkeeper.client.PulsarMockReadHandle
[INFO] Running org.apache.zookeeper.MockZooKeeper
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.063 s - in org.apache.zookeeper.MockZooKeeper
[INFO] Tests run: 73, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 23.832 s - in org.apache.bookkeeper.mledger.impl.ManagedLedgerTest
```

Hours later, the log still looks the same. When I run the tests in ManagedLedgerTest, they all pass. So, it seems like there's a test after ManagedLedgerTest that it's hanging on. 
When I push the code to our build server, we see the exact same behavior. 
I tried running the tests from Maven with increased verbosity by adding the `-X` parameter, like this:
`mvn install -DfailIfNoTests=false '-Dtest=!KafkaProducerSimpleConsumerTest,!PrimitiveSchemaTest,!BlobStoreManagedLedgerOffloaderTest' -pl '!pulsar-broker,!pulsar-proxy,!pulsar-brokeruth-sasl,!pulsar-io/kafka-connect-adaptor,!tests/pulsar-storm-test' -X`

However, I'm not getting any additional information about what's hanging. (The output above is identical when `-X` is provided.)

How do I determine which test is hanging?

Answer (score 1):

1. Way: 
   Start the tests with remote debugging, look at surefire-documentation, how to do that.

When the test hangs, attach a debugger (intellij, netbeans, eclipse,...) and look into the stacktrace.

2. Way:
   Create a stackdump (use jstack) of the java-vm that is running the test. One of those stacks should show your hanging test.